# Bathroom Flooring Expanding and Contracting in the Wrong Seasons

Tags: bathroom, flooring

I understand that the flooring will expand in the summer and contract in the winter.  This is because the flooring will pick up humid air in the summer and release humid air in the winter.   Right?

Then why did the floor contract in the Summer?

Is this theory true about hardwood flooring as well as vinyl engineered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is a bit too vague to answer, but keep in mind that contraction and expansion are relative as far as the homeowner is concerned. The floor can contract relative to walls if the walls expand more than the floor in high temperature (or humidity).

Comment: Agreed. Could also be that the floor is still drying, if it was installed during a humid season. There are a hundred theories for this one.

Comment: What???  You guys think that the house expanded rather than the floor contracted?      you mentioned there are a hundred theories, can you give me four?